# How to print each element of a string array in a different time gap?

Tags: java, timer

I have done enough research and found some similar Q-A. But I am not able to find the exact way.

I am having a string array:

```
public static String[] lyric = {"It's been a long day without you, my friend",
            "And I'll tell you all about it when I see you again",
            "We've come a long way from where we began",
            "Oh, I'll tell you all about it when I see you again",
            "When I see you again",
            "Damn, who knew?",
            "All the planes we flew",
            "Good things we've been through",
            "That I'll be standing right here talking to you"};
```

I want to print each letters of the sentence(element) in the array one by.
I want to give time gap between words too.
Then even in sentences.

For example: Every letter should be printed in 1/2 second of gap.
Then I want to give time period in words and in sentences.

Here I,m getting error in printing letters only

```
public class OperationPlay {
    public static String[] para;
    public static char[] singleW;
    public static int i,j,k;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        for (i = 0; i < Lyrics.lyric.length; i++) {
        para = Lyrics.lyric[i].split(" ");
        for (j = 0; j < para.length; j++) {
            singleW = para[j].toCharArray();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (k = 0; k < singleW.length; k++) {
                        System.out.print(singleW[k]);
                    }
                }
            }, 6000);

        }
    }

}
```

somebody help me out to perform this operation.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also it will finish both for loops in the run method at the same time

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177137/javafx-typewriter-effect-for-label

Comment: Simpler to just keep track of the next character in the lyric and how many ticks/intervals have elapse since the last character was output, then ensure that you've waited the appropriate interval based on whether it's a letter, space, or new sentence, and use the `schedule` overload that takes an interval

Answer (score 0):

You could just treat the entire set of lyrics as one long string and then go character-by-character, writing the next character if enough time has elapsed, using a recurring timer.

In this example, I run the timer every 5 milliseconds and assume every letter is printed after 5ms, every space every 10ms, every new line after 20ms.

```
public class OperationPlay 
{
        private static final char lineSeparator = '/';
        static int ticksSinceLastWrite = 0;
        static int indexOfNextCharacter = 0;
        private static final int ticksPerLetter = 1;
        private static final int ticksPerSpace = 2;
        private static final int ticksPerLine = 4;
        private static final int millisecondsPerTick = 5;
        static String allLyrics = "";


        public static boolean Tick()
        {

            ticksSinceLastWrite++;
            if (indexOfNextCharacter >= allLyrics.length())
            {
                return false;
            }

            int ticksForNextCharacter = 0;
            switch(allLyrics.charAt(indexOfNextCharacter))
            {
                case ' ':
                    ticksForNextCharacter = ticksPerSpace;
                    break;
                case lineSeparator:
                    ticksForNextCharacter = ticksPerLine;
                    break;
                default:
                    ticksForNextCharacter = ticksPerLetter;
            }

            if (ticksForNextCharacter <= ticksSinceLastWrite)
            {
                WriteNextCharacter();
            }

            return true;
        }

        private static void WriteNextCharacter()
        {
            char nextChar = allLyrics.charAt(indexOfNextCharacter);
            if (nextChar == lineSeparator)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(nextChar);
            }
            indexOfNextCharacter++;
            ticksSinceLastWrite = 0;
        }

      public static String[] lyric = {"It's been a long day without you, my friend",
            "And I'll tell you all about it when I see you again",
            "We've come a long way from where we began",
            "Oh, I'll tell you all about it when I see you again",
            "When I see you again",
            "Damn, who knew?",
            "All the planes we flew",
            "Good things we've been through",
            "That I'll be standing right here talking to you"};
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        allLyrics = String.join(Character.toString(lineSeparator), lyric);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean returnValue = Tick();
                if (returnValue == false)
                {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        }, 0, millisecondsPerTick );

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread.sleep(delay) which stop the thread for given time

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // change delay time as you require
        final long sentance_delay=1000; 
        final long word_delay=100;
        final long char_delay=50;


        for (i = 0; i < lyric.length; i++) {
        para = lyric[i].split(" ");
        for (j = 0; j < para.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(" "); // add space btween words
            Thread.sleep(word_delay);
            char [] word_chars=para[j].toString().toCharArray();
            for(k=0;k<word_chars.length;k++){
                System.out.print(word_chars[k]); //print chars one by one
                Thread.sleep(word_delay);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        Thread.sleep(sentance_delay);
    }


}
```